# Using line breaks from VB.Net to XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am writing data from a vb project to an XML document. When I recall the data, all the previous notes are coming back as one long line of text. How can I break the lines by submission to the XMl document?

Code:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles     btnSave.Click

        Dim AcctNum = txtAcctNum.Text.ToString

        'Dim note1 As String = ""

        'Dim linebreak As String = "<br />"

        'Str & VBNewLine
        'Str & VBCrLf

        Dim note2 As String = TxtNotes.Text
        'note2(0) = vbNewLine
        'note2(1) = TxtNotes.Text()

        Dim note3 As String = txtPastNote.Text

        note2 = note3 + "\n" + note2

        Dim root As XElement = XElement.Load("CreditApp.xml")

        Dim customer = From el In root.<custData>
                       Where el.<AcctNum>.Value = AcctNum
                       Select el

        For Each element In customer
            element.SetElementValue("Note", note2)
        Next

        'Dim NewNote As String = note1 + note2

        'Dim doc As New XmlDocument
        'doc.Load("CreditApp.xml")

        'Dim custData As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("custData")

        'Dim note As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("Note")
        'note.InnerText = NewNote

        'custData.AppendChild(note)
        'doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(custData)

        root.Save("CreditApp.xml")
        MessageBox.Show("NOTES SAVE")

    End Sub
```

Code that retrieves the elements from XML:

```
 For Each element In customer
            txtSSN.Text = element.ssn
            txtfName.Text = element.fname
            txtlName.Text = element.lname
            txtAcctNum.Text = element.acctnum
            txtVerfiWord.Text = element.passcode
            txtAcctAmt.Text = element.acctAval
            txtAcctBal.Text = element.acctbal
            txtLPmtAmt.Text = element.lpmtamt
            txtLPmtDate.Text = element.lpmtdate
            txtGender.Text = element.gender
            txtAddress.Text = element.address
            txtCity.Text = element.city
            txtState.Text = element.state
            txtZip.Text = element.zip
            txtPhone.Text = element.phone
            txtEmail.Text = element.email
            txtCreditLmt.Text = element.creditlim
            txtIntRate.Text = element.intrate
            txtMinPmtDue.Text = element.minpay
            txtPmtDueDate.Text = element.pmtduedate
            txtPastNote.Text = element.note

end sub
```

Comment: Can you add an example of how you are writing the data to the XML file?  Thanks.

Comment: What is the data source a file or a control?

Comment: @Wade73 - Its an XML file (document).

Comment: We tried adding a \n, <br /> and a vbNewLine in between the notes but none of these were successful

Comment: See if this [MSDN Forum Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/a9a48e2a-99f3-43f5-ae01-e907b2a7b878) is any help

Comment: @Mark Hall This did not help us. We have figured out that note2 & vbNewLine & note3 will store the note correctly in XML. What we need is when we pull the data out of the file, we need it to recognize new lines.

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using to import your data from the xml file?

Comment: @Mark Hall information has been added

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10298/discussion-between-kevin-schultz-and-mark-hall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am presumming that you are using a TextBox, its Multiline property is set to True and the character you are using for the NewLine is part of the string being input from the xml file, You can try using [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) or if you need to split into seperate Strings you can use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx)

```
txtPastNote.Text = element.note.Replace("\n", vbCrLf)
```